The imported package 'get_it' isn't a dependency of the importing package
I am working on a multimodule flutter project and have get_it and json_annotation dependencies added in pubspec.yaml file of shared library. I am importing this library in other modules.When I run flutter analyze command I am getting warning with message  The
imported package 'get_it' isn't a dependency of the importing package • packages/features/lib/feature1/dependencies.dart:2:8 •
The imported package 'json_annotation' isn't a dependency of the importing package •
          packages/libraries/repositories/lib/templates/test/comment_entity.dart:1:8 • depend_on_referenced_packages

Shared library pubspec.yaml file
name: shared
description: "A new Flutter package project."
version: 0.0.1
publish_to: "none"

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.3.1 <4.0.0'
  flutter: ">=1.17.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  get_it: ^7.7.0
  go_router: 14.1.0
  json_annotation: ^4.9.0
  json_serializable: 6.8.0
  localization:
    path: ../../localization

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: 4.0.0

flutter:

pubspec.yaml file of module in which this library is imported
name: database
description: "A new Flutter package project."
version: 0.0.1
publish_to: "none"


environment:
  sdk: '>=3.3.1 <4.0.0'
  flutter: ">=1.17.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  shared:
    path: ../shared
  repositories:
    path: ../repositories

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


flutter:

In shared.dart exporting the packages so other modules can find it.
library shared;
export 'package:get_it/get_it.dart';
export 'package:json_serializable/json_serializable.dart';
export 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';
export 'package:isar/isar.dart';
export 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

I checked below answer but as I am working on a multimodule project its not relevant.
The imported package 'path' isn't a dependency of the importing package
Also checked below resource but somehow its not working as well
How can I fix 'The imported package '' isn't a dependency of the importing package.' message on a project that uses a centralized dependency package
How this issue can be resolved?

Try after adding package to your pubspec.yaml, save the file and run flutter pub get in your terminal or IDE. This will download and add the package to your Flutter project.

But I have already added the package in shared library and shared library reference is added in pubspec.yaml file of other project. Should't it take reference from there?

It should indeed take reference from there, try to replace shared:
path: ../shared with path: ../  in pubspec.yaml file of module
and also ensure that you're importing the get_it package correctly in your Dart files within the shared library.

NO just replacing path: ../shared with path: ../ is not working

in your features package are you importing directly json_annotation or shared?
